# ACE Flex 3 : Handle Framework Events

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

In ACE Flex 3 , there is a topic
"Handle Framework Events"

Could you please point me to some document which lists all the 'required' framework events for ACE test? 
So i could know what are "framework" events and will focus on them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that's a tall order. You might want to look [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/events/package-detail.html) first, that's all of the events in the mx.events namespace. I can't imagine you'd need to memorize them all but rather know about them and the [component lifecycle](http://msimtiyaz.wordpress.com/flex/adobe-flex-component-instantiation-life-cycle/). However, I've never taken the test so I couldn't tell you exactly what they are looking for...